# Uniqueness of minimum cost flow and reduced cost optimality condition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, linear-programming, discrete-optimization, network-flow

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a directed graph with edge costs $c: E \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ and edge capacities $w: E \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$. Let $f^*: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ be a minimum cost flow, $\pi$ be a set of node labels or potentials such that $c^{\pi}((u,v)) = c((u,v)) - \pi(u) + \pi(v) \geq 0$. Let $G^{0}_{f^*}$ be the subgraph consisting of only edges of the residual graph $G_{f^*}$ with $c^{\pi}((u,v)) = 0$. How can I go about proving that $f^*$ is the unique minimum cost flow iff $G^{0}_{f^*}$ has a directed cycle with length of at least 3. I am aware that this question: [Nonzero Reduced Cost in Linear Programming Optimal Solution Implies Uniqueness of Optimum?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4546008/nonzero-reduced-cost-in-linear-programming-optimal-solution-implies-uniqueness-o) is a more general version of mine but I would like to solve this problem without looking too deep into Linear Programming. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does $G$ have fixed source and target vertices? Is $f^*$ a minimum cost *maximum* flow? A minimum cost flow would just be the zero flow. And are you sure this is correct statement? Or do you mean that $G^0_{f^*}$ has *no* directed cycles with length of at least $3$?

Comment: I am not very familiar with minimum cost flows but this looks like a consequence of strong duality / the optimality conditions for linear programs. This is a non-trivial result, and I would not expect there to be a very easy proof in this special case. More precisely, I would expect that the "only if" part is not difficult, but the "if" part is relatively hard. But again, I have not thought deeply about this, so I might well be wrong.